# Making a folder inside AWS EC2 accessible from public

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new in using AWS EC2. I have deployed some of my scripts on AWS.

If I do `pwd` I see something like this :

```
/home/bitnami/folder/script.php
```

So, if I call from a browser :

```
<publicDNS>/folder/script.php
```

i get : `The requested url cannot be found on the server.`

How can it be accessed from outside? I see that AWS has a file htdocs which I expect, if I put it there it will be visible but I do not want to transfer all of my folder there. Can you help me with that?

EDIT : If I put the folder in htdocs I can call it. Does that mean that all of my project should be placed inside the htdocs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whats your document root path of your application.

You can check the document root path from the phpinfo function.

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

run in browser and find for variable 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'.
you will see the path something like below if its a ubuntu mechine, it might different for you.

```
/var/www/html/yourappfolder/.
```

Any file/folder you put inside the document root, you can access with the url like this

```
<publicDNS>/yourFolder/yourFile.php
```

But in your case you have file inside '/home/bitnami/folder/' folder which might not be the document root for your application. In that case you can transfer all those files to inside your document root folder

or

you can create a php file(for example - getFile.php) inside your application and serve all your outside files through this file, see the code below.

```
/*File name: getFile.php */  
 $fileName = $_GET['filename'];
 $cwd = getcwd(); // get the current working directory
 chdir ("/home/bitnami/folder/"); // Change directory to /home/bitnami/folder/
 require_once($fileName); // include the required file
 chdir ($cwd); // Change the directory to its original location
```

and your url for this would be like this

```
<publicDNS>/getFile.php?filename=script.php
```